# How can I ensure that gimp exports the right (solid) color?

Tags: color, gimp, website-design, css, hex

Steps to reproduce issue:

- create a new document
- fill layer with solid color (#4b4b6b)
- export as jpg (File > Export)
- New JPG color is #4b4c6b (i.e. not the same, notice the 3rd character)

When trying to match a css background color it's a real pain.

I use a colorpicker to ensure the fill color is indeed 4b4b6b
I use the same colorpicker to ensure the HTML document is 4b4b6b

Only the JPG is "wrong"

When I "Show preview in image window" (this option is in the export dialog) I can see the solid color changing ever so slightly. I've tried toggling every option in that dialog.

Is this a bug or is there a magic checkbox that will solve my problem?

---

A workaround is to export as PNG and convert PNG>JPG with another utility like imagemagick.

Comment: Everything color calibrated?

Comment: @scott It's all on the same equipment, the hex value shouldn't change, try it :-)

Comment: *hardware* calibration, while important, is not the same thing as proper color profiles for applications. An image editor is entirely capable of saving an image with color that appear incorrect on the same hardware.

Comment: Gimp has only 1 color profile (maybe you can add others, I haven't tried). *Color in* should be *color out* unless you are changing something in between. I've just now tried with Krita which is producing consistent results.

Comment: @nlambert color management can be hard to grasp even on same device it doe snot produce same result between profile aware and unaware software. Its working as intended you just havent put teh right values in. Also JPEG is not a good format for exact color reproduction

Comment: It's working in Krita and Photoshop, I have the same values in Gimp. @joojaa

Comment: @nlambert apparently its not. Something is different

Comment: @joojaa default values should work, as they do in PS and Krita. This isn't rocket science, an application should produce consistent results without having to experiment.

Comment: @nlambert actually color correction is comparable to rocket science. Also its pretty common that photoshop does not do this consistency by default either. It is in fact a much more commonly asked question. It entirely depends on hiw your os has been configured

Comment: @joojaa Although I've understood from the start what you are suggesting, I disagree with your reasoning. I believe software should work as expected. Especially when many others behave correctly (I've since tried with Affinity, Krita, PS, all producing consistent results).

Comment: @nlambert yes, im but disputing that but its not always possibe. Anyway, you can rage here all you want the truth is you must adjust your settings, log a bug or forego using gimp

Comment: @joojaa I've reread everything I wrote and I don't see anything that could be seen as rage. It's a question and if there is no answer then maybe it's a bug.

Comment: @nlambert its more likely the default settings just dont reflect your os settings well, or atleast more productive to think so. But instead of looking into it you just started telling default options should work. But clearly they dont. You can offcourse say its a bug but then there is no solution to your question until xxx months forward. Its better to accept that you need to fix it atkeast for now. I can not fix it for you because i have no acess to your settings

Answer (score 2):

JPG is a lossy format, you can't expect anything to remain the same. Save as a PNG to retain all information.

Comment: Could be the libjpeg library... ImageMagick does the same if I convert a 4b4b6b PNG to JPG.

Comment: Photoshop gets consistent results, Krita does as well, I've also tried putting the "quality" all the way DOWN in Krita, and all the way UP in Gimp. Krita produces consistent results, Gimp does not.

Comment: @nlambert so, [make a bug report](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gimp/-/issues). There's nothing we can do about it, and so there's no point complaining here.